# How to connect an back to intent in DialogFlow when the user's utterance is not recognized?

Tags: bots, dialogflow-es

I'm making a bot in Dialog Flow and I have some intents linked together. However, once I end up saying a phrase that's not part of the *user says*, the bot exits the whole chain of intents and disregards related contexts i try to input next.

Is there a way for me to avoid this situation?

Comment: Can you show examples (possibly of screen shots) of how you are "linking" the intents? Do you mean with Follow-Up Intents?

Comment: (i can't really show screen shots since the project's kind of..yeah. so i'll just try to explain it in words)
for example, for intentA, i added an output context called contextA, and use that as an input context for intentB. which is turn is connected by using an output context contextB, which will be used to connect to intentC.
the linking of the intents work perfectly fine, but when i end up mispronouncing an utterance for intentB, dialog flow completely exits the flow and i'd have to start over again, which would be completely inconvenient for a user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like i just needed to use fallback intents, as documented [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents#fallback_intents)